# Service Account Permissions to run a Taskschd.msc task

Tags: windows, active-directory, account, password-encryption

I have few reporting tasks which i created in taskschd.msc and for runing them i am using application account as they are IIS based jobs which needs application level access . 
Tasks like Website availability etc.....

Now for security reasons I donot want to use my credentials or Application service account anymore as I need to input plain text password. So i am planning to request OS team to create a AD Service account .

So what could be the least permissions required by AD Service account to run a Windows task ?

Also how i can encrypt and place plain text password to be read by job and execute ?

Thanks

Comment: *So what could be the least permissions required by AD Service account to run a Windows task ?* -> Shouldn't that depend on what kind of task is that program intended to do?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful , Yes I accept and I did mention it is for reporting purpose like IIS Website availability , sites availability status reports etc .... I just want to encrypt the plain text password for this sake ... Thanks